# How to change page size of pagelayout for printing custom size?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-9.3

I have a A3 printer (size: 297mm x 420mm). But I am wanting to print my pagelayout with paper size is: 265mm x 380mm

I tried to change the page size of my pagelayout to 265mm x 380mm by using the statement:

```
pageLayout.Page.PutCustomSize(26.5, 38);                
 pageLayout.Page.Orientation = 2;
```

And, I tried to setup printer properties to A3 size or custom size (265mm x 380mm) but it is not successfull (it shows incorrect position).

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: have you set the unit using for eg mapDocument.PageLayout.Page.Units = esriUnits.esriMillimeters;

Comment: @geogeek: Thank you. I haven't set it. I will check

Comment: Are you still using ArcGIS 9.3 to try and do this? If not, what ArcGIS for Desktop version are you using? Did you try @geogeek's advice? You can use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with these details.

Comment: Hi @PolyGeo, I resolved this problem by creating a customed page size in Printer Setting.